# what is the work of R.java and BuildConfig.java both are auto generated files

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in android development.
I ant to the use of R.java and BuildConfig.java both are auto generated files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R.java is the way Android provide resource access from within your code. As you wrote or when you alters xml files etc on save of that resource file Android SDK will recompile the R class to make your changes accessible for within your code.

Answer (score 1):

R.java maps your resource adresses to static int variables, which provides ease of use to you.
BuildConfig.java specifies special flags such as DEBUG which are interpreted by dalvik machine  to allow debug for your app

Answer (score 1):

R.java file auto-generated file. It stores the all Id's and drawable names and class names etc.., and build config file maintains the build generation process